# Special Relativity Equation

Tags: special-relativity

The relativistic kinetic energy can found by the formula $$KE=mc^2-m_0c^2.$$ From this equation, how do you show that at low speeds the $KE$ is given by $KE=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$? 
So far I got:
$$KE=\frac{m_0c^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}-m_0c^2$$
$$KE=m_0c^2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}-1\right)$$
I couldn't figure out how to finish it from there.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you are trying to work out what happens in a situation where $a \ll b$, for some variables $a$ and $b$, you should immediately think of using a [binomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem). This tells us that we can expand the expression:

$$ \left( 1 + \frac{a}{b}\right)^n = 1 + n\frac{a}{b} + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2 + \text{and so on} $$

The reason this is so useful is that if $a \ll b$ then $a/b \ll 1$ and the squared and higher terms in $a/b$ are so small they can be ignored. We get the approximation:

$$ \left( 1 + \frac{a}{b}\right)^n \approx 1 + n\frac{a}{b} $$

In this particular case we have an equation for the total energy:

$$\begin{align}
 E &= \gamma m c^2 \\
   &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}} m c^2 \\
   &= \left(1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^{-1/2} m c^2
\end{align}$$

And using the binomial theorem we get the approximation:

$$ \left(1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^{-1/2} \approx 1 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2} $$

Substitute this in the expression for $E$ above and the result you want drops straight out.

Note that as a rule we don't encourage questions asking essentially *how do I do this calculation*, but knowing how to the use the binomial theorem is so important that it's worth making an exception. You'll find yourself using the binomial theorem all over physics so it's a vital tool to have in your toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Do a Taylor expansion of 
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x ^2}}$
and it'll come right out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand the first term in the bracket on the assumption that $v\ll c$.

$KE=m_0c^2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}-1\right) \approx m_0c^2\left( 1+\dfrac 12 \dfrac {v^2}{c^2}+......  -1\right )\approx \dfrac 12 m_0v^2$